# Process nested map's key values from a list

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a mongo collection which returns a nested map whose content is as follows:

```
Root={id=8080, status=OK, rootSource=[{sid=CITY, value=1234, Date=2011-04-11}, {sid=CTRY, value=4321, Date=2011-04-09}]}
```

I have to perform two separate operations on it:

1. Extract both the value items i.e., 1234 and 4321
2. Check if value items i.e., 1234 and 4321 exist or not.

I have tried below for the first part's first value i.e., 1234 which fails (hence have not tried second part yet):

```
((Map<String, ArrayList<Object>>) (data.get("Root")).get("rootSource")).get("value").toString()
```

Exception is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

There is another map which is returned, which is like below:

Root={id=9090, status=OK, rootSource={sid=CITY, value=9999, Date=2011-04-11}}

And I handle it like:

```
((Map<String, Object>) (data.get("Root")).get("rootSource")).get("value").toString()
```

But the list part fails for obvious reasons.

What is the effective way to perform the two tasks.

Comment: Since the value of `rootSource` is a `List<Map<String, Object>>`, you have to **iterate** the list. I see no attempt at iterating a list. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear isn't it? At some point there is an array of maps, not a map of maps. I'm guessing this should work to get the first value (without casts):

```
data.get("Root").get("rootSource")).get(0).get("value").toString()
```

What type is `data`? It sounds horrible to have to cast everywhere with generic types (which means the casts are unchecked).

Comment: Its: Map<String, Map> data = new HashMap<String, Map>(); Had to keep it like this because mongo document is not in a fix schema

Comment: Well it seems like `rootSource` is a list of maps, just see how it's displayed in textual form.